# How to deal with that loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

trying to write a code for a loop, that takes numbers from input until the input is "The End". At that moment the loop should stop and return the sum of all the numbers entered before "The End". I have a intuitive feeling that it should be super easy to perform, however I am stuck with that code. Need an impulse. I thought something like that, but as i try to convert inputs into integers in order to sum them, it returns an error when i finally input "The End" as it is logically can not become an integer.

```
n = 0
summa = 0
while n != "The End":
    n = input()
    summa += int(n)

print(summa)
```

Comment: Which Language? Specify the language, so that right people can reach you.

Answer (score 0):

```
while n != "The End":
    n = input()
    # At this part, add check if n is integer, update new summa, otherwise no action
    summa += int(n)
```